# What are the consequences of $\mathsf{L}^2 \subseteq \mathsf{P}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, conditional-results, structural-complexity

We know that $\mathsf{L} \subseteq \mathsf{NL} \subseteq \mathsf{P}$ and that $\mathsf{L} \subseteq \mathsf{NL} \subseteq \mathsf{L}^2 \subseteq $ [$\mathsf{polyL}$](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:P#polyl), where $\mathsf{L}^2 = \mathsf{DSPACE}(\log^2 n)$. We also know that $\mathsf{polyL} \neq \mathsf{P}$ because the latter has complete problems under logarithmic space many-one reductions while the former does not (due to the space hierarchy theorem). In order to understand the relationship between $\mathsf{polyL}$ and $\mathsf{P}$, it may help to first understand the relationship between $\mathsf{L}^2$ and $\mathsf{P}$.

What are the consequences of $\mathsf{L}^2 \subseteq \mathsf{P}$?

What about the stronger $\mathsf{L}^{k} \subseteq \mathsf{P}$ for $k>2$, or the weaker $\mathsf{L}^{1 + \epsilon} \subseteq \mathsf{P}$ for $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: Why doesn't polyL has complete problems under logarithmic space many-one reductions? I don't see why the space hierarchy theorem should be a problem. E.g., the class E (linear-exponential time) has complete problems under linear time reductions despite the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: @OrMeir I recently added an explanation of this fact to [the Wikipedia article for polyL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PolyL).

Comment: I think the following is an obvious consequence, and especially not a surprising one : $L^2 \subseteq P$ would imply that $L \neq P$, because otherwise it would contradict the space hierarchy $L \subsetneq L^2$.

Comment: it would seem to be a strengthening of the [Hopcroft/Paul/Valiant result](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/we-believe-a-lot-but-can-prove-little/) which uses "pebbling" arguments. and similar to a "space compression algorithm" but complexity theory seems not to have been studied lots from that perspective, and/or the perspective is difficult (ie not any easier than hard complexity class separations that resist attack)

Comment: @SajinKoroth It seems that no one has a better answer than yours, and although you may consider it obvious and unsurprising, it is indeed a correct answer. If you create an official "answer" to the question, I will reward the bounty to you.

Comment: @argentpepper : I don't think its worthy of the bounty. :), please reserve your bounty points for such interesting questions you are going to ask in the future.

Comment: Neat question!  I think it's definitely worth a bounty.  Btw, here is a simple observation, if $L^2 \subseteq P$, then $DSPACE(n) \subseteq DTIME(2^{O(\sqrt{n})})$.  Therefore, we have a more efficient algorithm for CNF-SAT and we refute ETH (Exponential time hypothesis).

Comment: Following @MichaelWehar's comment, the implication follows from a standard [padding argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_argument) that extends to weaker hypotheses: if $L^{1 + \epsilon}$ is in $P$, then any problem that can be solved in linear space (including the satisfiability problem), can be solved in time $2^{O\left(n^{\frac{1}{1 + \epsilon}}\right)}$.

Comment: Yep.  Thanks for the follow-up.  :)

Comment: @SajinKoroth: I think your comment, as well as Michael Wehar's (and argentpepper's follow-up) should be answers...

Comment: Agreed with Joshua.  This is a satisfactory set of consequences, and one should not have to dive deep into the comment section to get it.  @SajinKoroth, would you mind writing it?

Comment: should I add the answers of Michael Wehar's answer and agent pepper's follow up as part of my answer and cite them ?

Comment: @SajinKoroth: Yes, that would be best, especially if you put your answer as "community wiki".

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised if $L^2 \subseteq P$ implied that $NL^2 \subseteq NP$.  What do you think?

Comment: Hi again!!  You can define these seemingly unnatural $L^k$ complete problems from certain $XL$-complete parameterized problems.  There are these parameterized problems (let's denote the parameter by $k$) that are $XL$-complete where if we make $k$ depend on the input size $n$ such that $k = O(\log^{k-1}(n))$, then we obtain a decision problem that is $L^k$-complete.

Comment: @user124864 The idea for this can be found here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-55808-X_33

Comment: @user124864 In regards to your third question, in addition to everything else mentioned here, we would get $P \neq NL$.  But, I can't think of much else.  I'm happy to discuss this with you more if you're interested.  I hope that you have a nice day.  :)

Comment: Unrelated observation: I think that $L^2 \subseteq P$ would also imply that $XL \subseteq$ non-uniform $FPT$.

Comment: @user124864 We should really connect and chat about these things sometime.  :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The following is an obvious consequence:
$\mathsf{L}^{1+\epsilon} \subseteq \mathsf{P}$ would imply $\mathsf{L} \subsetneq \mathsf{P}$ and therefore $\mathsf{L} \neq \mathsf{P}$.

By the space hierarchy theorem, $\forall \epsilon > 0: \mathsf{L} \subsetneq \mathsf{L}^{1+\epsilon}$ . 
If $\mathsf{L}^{1+\epsilon} \subseteq \mathsf{P}$ then $\mathsf{L} \subsetneq \mathsf{L}^{1+\epsilon} \subseteq \mathsf{P}$.

Comment: Small footnote: If $P \neq L$, then we have $P \neq NL$ or $NL \neq L$.

Answer (score 28):

$
\newcommand{\DSPACE}{\mathsf{DSPACE}}
\newcommand{\L}{\mathsf{L}}
\newcommand{\P}{\mathsf{P}}
\newcommand{\DTIME}{\mathsf{DTIME}}
$

$\L^2 \subseteq \P$ would refute the [Exponential Time Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis).

If $\L^2 \subseteq \P$ 
then by a [padding argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_argument)
$\DSPACE(n) \subseteq \DTIME(2^{O(\sqrt n)})$. 
This means that the satisfiability problem $\mathsf{SAT} \in \DSPACE(n)$
can be decided in $2^{o(n)}$ steps, 
refuting the Exponential Time Hypothesis.

More generally,
$\DSPACE(\log^{k} n) \subseteq \P$ for $k\geq1$
implies
$\mathsf{SAT} \in \DSPACE(n) \subseteq 
\DTIME(2^{O(n^{\frac{1}{k}})})$.

(This answer is expanded from a comment by @MichaelWehar.)

Comment: Thank you for expanding on the comment!  I appreciate it.  :)

Comment: In addition, the last hypothesis also implies that $QBF$ is in DSPACE($n$) $\subseteq$ DTIME($2^{O(n^{\frac{1}{k}})}$).

Answer (score 8):

Group isomorphism (with groups given as multiplication tables) would be in P. Lipton, Snyder, and Zalcstein showed this problem is in $\mathsf{L}^2$, but it is still open whether it is in P. The best current upper bound is $n^{O(\log n)}$-time, and because it reduces to graph isomorphism, stands as a significant obstacle to putting graph iso into P.

Makes me wonder what other natural and important problems this would apply to: that is, in $\mathsf{L}^2$ but with their best known time upper bound quasi-polynomial.

Comment: More specifically, the more general problem of quasigroup isomorphism is in $\beta_2 \mathsf{FOLL}$, which is a subclass of $\mathsf{L}^2$.

Comment: Also, the group rank problem (given a finite group *G* as a multiplication table and an integer *k*, does *G* have a generating set of cardinality *k*?) also has this property. The algorithm is just a search over the subsets of *G* of cardinality *k* but uses two important facts: (1) each finite group has a generating set of logarithmic size and (2) subgroup membership is in $\mathsf{SL}$, which equals $\mathsf{L}$.

Comment: What is $\mathsf{\beta_2FOLL}$?

Comment: AC circuits of depth $O(\log \log n)$ that also accept $O(\log^2 n)$ nondeterministic bits.

Answer (score 2):

**Claim:** If $L^k \subseteq P$ for some $k > 2$, then $P \neq \log(CFL)$ and $P \neq NL$.

> Suppose that $L^k \subseteq P$ for some $k > 2$.
>
> From "[Memory bounds for recognition of context-free and context-sensitive languages](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1687178)", we know that $CFL \subseteq DSPACE(\log^2(n))$.  By the space hierarchy theorem, we know that $DSPACE(\log^2(n)) \subsetneq DSPACE(\log^k(n))$.
>
> Therefore, we get $\log(CFL) \subseteq DSPACE(\log^2(n)) \subsetneq DSPACE(\log^k(n)) \subseteq P$.
>
> Also, by Savitch's Theorem, we know that $NL \subseteq L^2$. Therefore, we get $NL \subseteq DSPACE(\log^2(n)) \subsetneq DSPACE(\log^k(n)) \subseteq P$.