# On $\mathcal L$, $\mathcal{N\!L}$, $\mathcal L^2$, $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal{N\!P}$

Tags: reference-request, complexity-classes, open-problem, hierarchy-theorems

We know that $\mathcal{L}\subseteq \mathcal{N\!L}\subseteq\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathcal{N\!P}$. From Savitch's Theorem, $\mathcal{N\!L}\subseteq\mathcal{L}^2$, and, from Space Hierarchy Teorem, $\mathcal{L}\neq\mathcal{L}^2$. So, as we don't know if $\mathcal L\neq\mathcal P$, we don't know if $\mathcal L^2\subseteq\mathcal P$, or do we know that $\mathcal L^2\not\subseteq\mathcal P$? Has anybody been trying to prove that $\mathcal L^2\subseteq\mathcal P$? What are the latest results, or efforts, in this way? I've been trying to write a survey on this topic, but haven't found anything relevant.

Furthermore, whether exists or not a $\mathcal{N\!P}$ problem which is not $\mathcal{N\!P}$-complete is an open question, and such existence would imply $\mathcal L\neq\mathcal{N\!P}$, as every $\mathcal L$ problem is complete for $\mathcal L$. But do we really not know that $\mathcal L\neq\mathcal{N\!P}$? Has anybody been trying to prove this? Again, what are the latest results, or efforts, in this way?

Maybe I'm missing something, or searching wrongly, but I couldn't find anyone working on the $\mathcal L^2\subseteq \mathcal P$ and $\mathcal L\neq\mathcal{N\!P}$ questions.

Comment: I asked a subset of this question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14159/4193

Comment: We don't know any separation between $\mathsf{TC^0}$ and $\mathsf{NExpTime}$. So any strict containment among classes between them is unknown. Does this plus @argentpepper's [What are the consequences of $\mathsf{L}^2 \subseteq \mathsf{P}$?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14159/4193) question answer your questions?

Comment: Steve Cook with his colleagues has been working on an approach to separate $\mathsf{P}$ from $\mathsf{L}$. I think the following is their most recent published work on it:  Stephen Cook,
Pierre McKenzie,
Dustin Wehr,
Mark Braverman,
Rahul Santhanam,
 ["Pebbles and Branching Programs for Tree Evaluation"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2077336.2077337), 2012.

Comment: @Kaveh We certainly know that **UNIFORM** $TC^0$ is different from $P^{\#P}$ -- cf. Allender's circuit lower bounds for the Permanent. (Uniform $TC^0$ is the version that is relevant to the present discussion.) But yes, even separating $NP$ from uniform-$TC^0$ is open.

Comment: @Ryan, you are right, I was thinking of nonuniform $\mathsf{TC^0}$, what matters here is uniform version as you wrote.

Answer (score 12):

You can check the following paper:

[Translational lemmas, polynomial time, and $ (\log n)^j$-space](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900578) by Ronald V. Book (1976).

Figures 1 and 2 in the paper give the summary of what is known and what is unknown.

I put Theorem 3.10 in the paper here:

- $ DTIME(poly(n)) \neq DSPACE(poly(\log n)) $;
- for every $ j \geq 1 $, $ DTIME(n^j) \neq DSPACE(poly(\log n)) $;
- for every $ j,k \geq 1 $, $ DTIME(n^j) \neq DSPACE( (\log n)^k ) $.

Comment: A free online copy is [here](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr32.pdf).